# Scipy: linkage labels to output Z

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I calculate the distance between words/sentences and run them through the scipy linkage function but I need to know how to relate it back to the original input. I.e. I lose my labels along the way since the linkage function doesn't accept that.

tl;dr;
I don't know how to relate my labels (var X) back to the output of the linkage function.

```
X = [
    "the weather is good",
    "it is a rainy day",
    "it is raining today",
    "This has something to do with today",
    "This has something to do with tomorrow",
]

# my magic function

result_set = [['this has something to do with today', 'this has something to do with tomorrow', 0.95044514149501169], 
    ['this has something to do with today', 'it is a rainy day', 0.27315656750393491], 
    ['this has something to do with today', 'it is raining today', 0.21404567560988952], 
    ['this has something to do with today', 'the weather is good', 0.12284646267479128], 
    ['this has something to do with tomorrow', 'it is a rainy day', 0.28564020977046212], 
    ['this has something to do with tomorrow', 'it is raining today', 0.19174771483161279], 
    ['this has something to do with tomorrow', 'the weather is good', 0.12920110156248313], 
    ['it is a rainy day', 'it is raining today', 0.54390124565447373], 
    ['it is a rainy day', 'the weather is good', 0.20843820300588964], 
    ['it is raining today', 'the weather is good', 0.19278767792873652]]

sims = np.array(result_set)[:, 2]
sims = ['0.950445141495' '0.273156567504' '0.21404567561' '0.122846462675'
     '0.28564020977' '0.191747714832' '0.129201101562' '0.543901245654'
     '0.208438203006' '0.192787677929']

Z = linkage(sims, 'ward')
Z = [[ 0.          4.          0.12284646  2.        ]
    [ 1.          3.          0.19174771  2.        ]
    [ 2.          5.          0.27143491  3.        ]
    [ 6.          7.          0.70328415  5.        ]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was entering similarity into a distance function, so after inverting the sim the outcome did make sense. The following does correctly display the labels

```
dendrogram(
    Z,
    labels=X,
    orientation="right",
    leaf_rotation=0,  # rotates the x axis labels
    leaf_font_size=8,  # font size for the x axis labels
)
```